# Round a float to 3dp? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point

How do I round a float to three decimal places?

I have this:

```
(round(1000.0f * currentHue) / 1000.0f)
```

Which rounds it to 3 decimal places but leaves a bunch of 0s on the end.

Answer (score 4):

Most numbers can't be represented precisely with floating point. If you need precision that bad pick appropriate scientific library. If you want to print it nicely, use formatters -

```
NSLog(@"%.3f", currentHue);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly hairy way to do it...  But it should work.

```
float x = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.3f",(round(1000.0f * currentHue) / 1000.0f)] floatValue];
```